# LNK2020: unresolved token (06000001) & LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001E)

Tags: c++-cli

I have written a wrapper layer in Managed C++ that interface to an API layer for a third party software written in Native C++. Now the wrapper compiles and build corretly. The build order is as follows:
(1) The third party API (Native C++ and built as a library),
(2) My warpper layer in Managed C++ (C++/CLR and built as a library),
(3) Main application written in Managed C++ using my wrapper to communicate with the third party API.

Now, in my wrapper layer there are some classes that I want to use in the Main application layer (in 3 above) thus the methods that I want to expose, I have written an interface class for thus only expose what I need to layer 3 (i.e. Main application layer). An example of which is shown below:

```
namespace RvBeehdClientApiWrapper
{
public ref class BeehdClientInitParamsWapper : public IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper
{
public:
    BeehdClientInitParamsWapper();

    ~BeehdClientInitParamsWapper();

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_VideoOutHwnd(unsigned long long^ newVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_VideoOutHwnd(unsigned long long newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_VideoLocalOutHwnd(unsigned long long^ newVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_VideoLocalOutHwnd(unsigned long long  newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_VideoOutPncHwnd(unsigned long long^ pVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_VideoOutPncHwnd(unsigned long long newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_ConfigFilePath(String^ pVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_ConfigFilePath(String^ newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_ProgramDataPath(String^ pVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_ProgramDataPath(String^ newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_LogFilesNumber(unsigned long^ pVal)  { return true; };
    virtual bool put_LogFilesNumber(unsigned long newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_LogFilesSize(unsigned long^ pVal)  { return true; };
    virtual bool put_LogFilesSize(unsigned long newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_LogsPath(String^ pVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_LogsPath(String^ newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_LicenseFilePath(String^ pVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_LicenseFilePath(String^ newVal);

    ///*virtual*/ bool get_IotFilePath(String^ pVal) { return true; };
    virtual bool put_IotFilePath(String^ newVal);

    virtual bool put_HistoryFilePath(String^ newVal);

    virtual bool put_IsAppLogEnabled(bool newVal);

    virtual bool put_IsLogContinuityOnStart(bool newVal);

    const CBeehdClientInitParamsImpl* get_InitializationParams() { return m_InitializationParams; }


private:
    CBeehdClientInitParamsImpl*          m_InitializationParams;

};
}
```

And its interface class is as follows:

```
namespace RvBeehdClientApiWrapper
{
public interface class IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper
{
    bool put_VideoOutHwnd(unsigned long long newVal);
    bool put_VideoLocalOutHwnd(unsigned long long  newVal);
    bool put_VideoOutPncHwnd(unsigned long long newVal);
    //bool get_ConfigFilePath(String^ pVal);
    bool put_ConfigFilePath(String^ newVal);
    //bool get_ProgramDataPath(String^ pVal);
    bool put_ProgramDataPath(String^ newVal);
    //bool get_LogFilesNumber(unsigned long^ pVal);
    bool put_LogFilesNumber(unsigned long newVal);
    //bool get_LogFilesSize(unsigned long^ pVal);
    bool put_LogFilesSize(unsigned long newVal);
    //bool get_LogsPath(String^ pVal);
    bool put_LogsPath(String^ newVal);
    //bool get_LicenseFilePath(String^ pVal);
    bool put_LicenseFilePath(String^ newVal);
    //bool get_IotFilePath(String^ pVal);
    bool put_IotFilePath(String^ newVal);
    bool put_HistoryFilePath(String^ newVal);
    bool put_IsAppLogEnabled(bool newVal);
    bool put_IsLogContinuityOnStart(bool newVal);
};
}
```

The main application layer uses the BeehdClientInitParamsWapper through a Factory class. The factory class's job is to create a singleton instance of the BeehdClientInitParamsWapper class and return the instance so that it can be used to get at the exposed methods exposed by the IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper class. Please see below the implementation of the Factory class for BeehdClientInitParamsWapper:

```
#pragma once
 #include "IApiWrapperClass.h"

 using namespace System;

namespace RvBeehdClientApiWrapper
{
ref class ApiWrapperClass;

public interface class IApiWrapperFactory
{
    IApiWrapperClass^ GetWrapperApiInstance();
};

public ref class ApiWrapperFactory : public IApiWrapperFactory
{
public:
    ApiWrapperFactory() {}
    ~ApiWrapperFactory() {}

    virtual IApiWrapperClass^ GetWrapperApiInstance();

private:

    static ApiWrapperClass^  m_theWrapperInstance;
};
}
```

The body of the factory class is as follows:

```
   #include "ApiWrapperFactory.h"
   #include "RvBeehdClientApiWrapper.h"


   RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::IApiWrapperClass^   RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::ApiWrapperFactory::GetWrapperApiInstance()
   {
     if (m_theWrapperInstance == nullptr)
     {
        m_theWrapperInstance = gcnew ApiWrapperClass();
     }
     return m_theWrapperInstance;
   }
```

The Main application layer (3 above) uses the methods as follows:

```
#include "BeehdClientInitParamsFactory.h"
#include "IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper.h"

bool RifMCDllMain::Start(...)
{
bool success = true;

try
{
    // Store the passed in RCA Config data reference.
    CConfigDetails ^ config = CConfigDetails::Instance;
    config->UseRcaConfig(rcaConfig);

    if (config->ReadConfigData())
    {
        // 1. Call Wrapper to populate the parameter object.
        RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::BeehdClientInitParamsFactory^ _ptrWrapperParamFactory = 
            gcnew RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::BeehdClientInitParamsFactory();
        RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper^ _pwrapperparameters =
            _ptrWrapperParamFactory->get_WrapperInitParamsInstance();

        //Populate the parameter object.
        _pwrapperparameters->put_VideoOutHwnd(5049174);
        _pwrapperparameters->put_VideoLocalOutHwnd(992466);
        _pwrapperparameters->put_VideoOutPncHwnd(468162);
        ...
    }
    else
    {
        _log->Error("Read RIF config data failed");
        success = false;
    }
```

After all that are implemented I compile the solution in the following order:
(i) The third party API (Native C++ and built as a library) -> **This compiles and creates a library**
(ii) My wrapper layer in Managed C++ (C++/CLR and built as a library) -> **This compiles and creates my wrapper library**
(iii) Main application written in Managed C++ using my wrapper to communicate with the third party API -> **This produces the following linkage error:**

[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCLmY.png)

[Compilation error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFjYp.png)

Please advise since I am really stuck.
Many thanks in advance.

**Please see the compilation error below:**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: RifMC, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConfigurationDetails.obj : /DEBUG:FASTLINK is not supported when managed code is present; restarting link with /DEBUG:FULL
1>ConfigurationDetails.obj : MSIL module encountered; incremental linking is disabled for MSIL; performing full link
1>RifMCDllMain.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001E) for 'RvBeehdClientApiWrapper.ApiWrapperClass'; image may not run
1>RifMCDllMain.obj : warning LNK4248: unresolved typeref token (0100001F) for 'RvBeehdClientApiWrapper.BeehdClientInitParamsWapper'; image may not run
1>RifMCDllMain.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000069) RvBeehdClientApiWrapper.ApiWrapperFactory::GetWrapperApiInstance
1>RifMCDllMain.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000070) RvBeehdClientApiWrapper.BeehdClientInitParamsFactory::get_WrapperInitParamsInstance
1>C:\Git\DSxMissionCriticals\DSxSuper\MissionCritical\RifMC\Debug\RifMC.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "RifMC.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

=========================================================================

```
namespace RvBeehdClientApiWrapper
{
ref class BeehdClientInitParamsWapper;

public interface class IBeehdClientInitParamsWapperFactory
{
    RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper^ get_WrapperInitParamsInstance();
};

public ref class BeehdClientInitParamsFactory : public IBeehdClientInitParamsWapperFactory
{
public:
    BeehdClientInitParamsFactory() {}

    ~BeehdClientInitParamsFactory() {}

    virtual RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper^ get_WrapperInitParamsInstance();

private:
    static BeehdClientInitParamsWapper^  m_theWrapperInitParamInstance;
};
}
```

### Body is shown below:

```
RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::IBeehdClientInitParamsWapper^ RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::BeehdClientInitParamsFactory::get_WrapperInitParamsInstance()
{
   if (m_theWrapperInitParamInstance == nullptr)
   {
       m_theWrapperInitParamInstance = gcnew  RvBeehdClientApiWrapper::BeehdClientInitParamsWapper();
   }
   return m_theWrapperInitParamInstance;
}
```

Comment: Please include your compilation error(s) in your post, so they are searchable and in case the link you referenced goes away.

Comment: The linker can't find get_WrapperInitParamsInstance().  When it is missing from the snippets as well then that usually means that you forgot to write it.

Comment: @Hans Passant : Yes I have actually  please see in the problem definition update above.